# ffmpeg stops reading rtsp livestream after some seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, live-streaming

I'm trying to save locally a rtsp livestream with ffmpeg but it stops after a few seconds. It works smooth, but suddently it just stops, more or less always after 10-15 seconds.

This is the command:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/test.sdp -c copy test.ts
```

And this is the log. I tried with previous ffmpeg versions with the same result:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-04-26-1128aa8 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 43.100 / 56. 43.100
  libavcodec     58. 82.100 / 58. 82.100
  libavformat    58. 42.101 / 58. 42.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 79.100 /  7. 79.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/test.sdp':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, 4.0, fltp
Output #0, mpegts, to 'test.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, 4.0, fltp
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  387 fps= 21 q=-1.0 Lsize=   18405kB time=00:00:16.91 bitrate=8912.2kbits/s speed=0.923x
video:17295kB audio:575kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.993069%
```

Debug shows also `"No more output streams to write to, finishing"` when it stops.

Could you help me, please? I don't know what else to try... Thank you.